# About lower upper bound of a subset of all topologies for a non empty set X

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, lattice-orders

[image]

How i may prove what is stated? That the topology generated using the theorem D as in the image, is equal to the lower upper bound of a non-empty family of topologies for a non empty set $X$.

Definitions: 
   The lower upper bound of a non-empty family of topologies of $X$ is the topology whose arise from the intersection of all topologies stronger than each topology in the family. 
A topology T is stronger than R if R is cointained in T.

I tried to prove that one set is cointained in the other by proving that every open set from one is in the another, but i could not, in special because the union of the topologies. One there know how to prove it or have a hint? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prove it in detail, all you have to show is that last statement:

> the class of all unions of finite intersections forms a topology

which is to say, this class is closed under the formation of finite intersection and arbitrary unions.

Doesn't it follow by construction?
(Notice that $\bigcup \varnothing = \varnothing$ and $\bigcap \varnothing = X$.)

Comment: i already proved it, my problem is more with the application of it, you have any idea about how i may apply the statement?

Comment: That is more difficult to say, I mean, a typical application. You can use it, for example, to generate topologies; for example, if you have a finite set and want to define all the topologies in that set. You might also use it to generate a (perhaps minimal) topology that separates two points $x_0$ and $x_1$. But I didn't check this last one; perhaps it's not useful except in very particular cases...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $T$ is a topology stronger than every topology in the family ${T_i}$.  Let $T'$ be the topology generated by the open subbase $\cup_i T_i$.  You need to prove that $T$ *contains*  $T'$.  If this is true then...

Edit: changed "$T$ is stronger than  $T'$" to "$T$ *contains*  $T'$". This should be more clear.

Comment: T` is a lower upper bound! thank you i think this is a good way :), just to confirm, also is necessary to show that T` is stronger than any topology in the family right?

Comment: i was working today on it, but i could not prove that if B is an open set on T`,  that is not in any topology $T_i$, is also an open set in T, and seems that it is not true...

Comment: In your second comment, I think you have confused my $T$ and $T'$.

Comment: To answer your first comment: Yes, it is necessary to explain why $T'$ will be stronger than any of the $T_i$'s in the family. This follows almost immediately from the definition of $T'$. Look carefully at the definition.

Comment: thank you for the help, just now i realized about an idea to the proof and finally proved it haha thank you, the idea was very simple, i just did not noticed the intuition behind the statement thank you ))